# Return both Result set AND a warning from a stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, db2

In Data Studio when you call `SYSPROC.ADMIN_CMD()` directly and it returns a warning, the results panel shows both the warning and the result set:

```
CALL SYSPROC.ADMIN_CMD('EXPORT TO /tmp/exportcat/storeent1.ixf OF IXF modified by codepage=1208 MESSAGES ON SERVER select  from storeent1' );

IWAQ0003W SQL warnings were found
SQLState=      Routine "SYSPROC.ADMIN_CMD" execution has completed, but at least one error, "SQL3022", was encountered during the execution. More information is available.. SQLCODE=20397, SQLSTATE=     , DRIVER=4.18.60
 ROWS_EXPORTED MSG_RETRIEVAL                                                                       MSG_REMOVAL
 ------------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ----------------------------------------------------
          NULL SELECT SQLCODE, MSG FROM TABLE(SYSPROC.ADMIN_GET_MSGS('180908937_DB2INST1')) AS MSG CALL SYSPROC.ADMIN_REMOVE_MSGS('180908937_DB2INST1')
```

I want to wrap it, so my proc retrieves and shos the details about the warning:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE xexport (
in @TABNAME VARCHAR(128)
, in @COLLIST CLOB
, in @WHERECOND CLOB
) DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1 MODIFIES SQL DATA
P1: BEGIN
    DECLARE SQLSTATE CHAR(5) DEFAULT '00000';
    DECLARE SQLCODE INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE @SAVESQLCODE INTEGER;
    DECLARE @SAVESQLSTATE CHAR(5);

    DECLARE LOC1 RESULT_SET_LOCATOR VARYING;
    DECLARE @S , @S2 CLOB;
    DECLARE @ROWS_EXPORTED BIGINT;
    DECLARE @MSG_RETRIEVAL , @MSG_REMOVAL CLOB;
    DECLARE @MYMSGS XML;

    DECLARE DETAILSCUR CURSOR FOR MSG_RETRIEVAL_STATEMENT;

    DECLARE MYMSGSCUR CURSOR WITH RETURN FOR
        SELECT M from XMLTABLE('$msgs/*/M' PASSING @MYMSGS AS "msgs"
        COLUMNS "M" CLOB PATH '.') AS U;

    if length(@COLLIST) > 0 then
    else
        SET @COLLIST = xtabcols4(UPPER(@TABNAME), '', 1, '');
    end if;

    SET @S = 'EXPORT TO /tmp/exportcat/' || LOWER(@TABNAME) || '.ixf OF IXF modified by codepage=1208 MESSAGES ON SERVER select ' || @COLLIST || ' from ' || @TABNAME || ' ' || @WHERECOND;
    SET @MYMSGS = XMLCONCAT( @MYMSGS , XMLELEMENT( NAME "M" , 'CALL SYSPROC.ADMIN_CMD(''' || REPLACE(@S,'''','''''') || ''')')); 

    BEGIN
        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION, SQLWARNING begin
            select SQLCODE , SQLSTATE into @SAVESQLCODE ,  @SAVESQLSTATE from sysibm.sysdummy1;
            if (@SAVESQLCODE < 0) then RESIGNAL; end if;

            SET @MYMSGS = XMLCONCAT( @MYMSGS , XMLELEMENT( NAME "M" , 'ADMIN_CMD() warning: SQLCODE=' || RTRIM(CAST(@SAVESQLCODE as char(100))) || ';SQLSTATE=''' || @SAVESQLSTATE || '''' ) ); 

            ASSOCIATE RESULT SET LOCATORS (LOC1) WITH PROCEDURE SYSPROC.ADMIN_CMD;
            ALLOCATE CUR1 CURSOR FOR RESULT SET LOC1;
            FETCH CUR1 INTO @ROWS_EXPORTED, @MSG_RETRIEVAL, @MSG_REMOVAL;
            PREPARE MSG_RETRIEVAL_STATEMENT FROM @MSG_RETRIEVAL;

            OPEN DETAILSCUR;
            BEGIN
                DECLARE @EOF INT DEFAULT 0;
                DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET @EOF = 1;
                FETCH FROM DETAILSCUR INTO @S, @S2;
                WHILE @EOF = 0 DO
                    SET @MYMSGS = XMLCONCAT( @MYMSGS , XMLELEMENT( NAME "M" , @S || ': ' || @S2 ) ); 
                    FETCH FROM DETAILSCUR INTO @S, @S2;
                END WHILE;
            END;
            CLOSE DETAILSCUR;

            SET @MYMSGS = XMLDOCUMENT( XMLELEMENT( NAME "R", '' , @MYMSGS ));
            OPEN MYMSGSCUR;

            --RESIGNAL;
        end;
        CALL SYSPROC.ADMIN_CMD( @S );
    END;
END
```

But if I uncomment `--RESIGNAL`, Data Studio only shows the warning